# Swift: Request authorization header is not set

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, sylius

I have a request endpoint for sylius [API](https://demo.sylius.com/api/v2/products) when I set the content-type header with `application/json` and the `Authorization` header with the **exact value** `Bearer SampleToken` through postman it responds fine with the intended response but when I try to set the request authorization header through `URLRequest` it gives me a response

```
{
    error = "access_denied";
    "error_description" = "OAuth2 authentication required";
}
```

when I monitor the request through charles I've noticed that the `Authorization` header is stripped off. I've tried many various ways to set the authorization header but with no luck.

```
func getTotalProducts(page:String){
    let urlPath="https://demo.sylius.com/api/v2/products"
    var request = URLRequest(url:  NSURL(string: urlPath)! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    request.setValue("Bearer SampleToken", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    Alamofire.request(request)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch(response.result){
            case .success(let value):
                print(value)
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print("something went wrong \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }.session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
}
```

The original postman request:

[image]

Comment: would you show the postman image?

Comment: @wings  sure I've updated the post and attached a screenshot for the postman request

Comment: Try passing the headers separately, see: https://grokswift.com/custom-headers-alamofire4-swift3/

Comment: would you add the app transport security settings in your app?

Comment: `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <string>YES</string>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>demo.sylius.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
 </dict>` @wings they already exists it in the app

Comment: @JonJ believe it or not I've tried all the methods used in the link but nothing works, could it be a problem related to the server, since the API made through PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
request.setValue("Bearer SampleToken", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

to

```
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
       "Authorization": "Bearer SampleToken",
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your authorization token should be a base64 encoded string of `user:password`

`request.setValue("Bearer base64EncodedString", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")`